# How to convert array string of MongoDB json to bson. C# Mongo Bson?

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, bson, jsonserializer

I have a file. The file has the following text:

```
[
{
    _id: ObjectId("5da08d49949b4c000100b90b"),
    ModifiedOn: ISODate("2019-10-11T14:10:17.461Z"),
    DateOfCreation: ISODate("2019-10-11T14:10:17.459Z"),
    DateModified: ISODate("2019-10-11T14:10:17.459Z"),
    Region: null,
    UniqueNumber: Long("465561"),
    Numiration: 1,
    Code: '001Е',
    User: { ID: ObjectId("someid") },
  }
  ]
```

I tried to do the following.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);
```

But it's not working. It will throw exception.

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: O. Path
> '[0]._id', line 3, position 9.

What i can do? I wanna convert this text to bsonarray. Without custom class.

I also tried to do that:

```
BsonArray array = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonArray>(str);
```

but it throw exception `JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'Long'.`

Comment: @YongShun Shun JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'Long'. It throw that exception

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectId(...)`, `Long(...)`, and `ISODate(...)` are not valid JSON.

If you have the object in the mongo shell, you might try using the `tostrictjson` built-in function to convert it, but note that the mongo shell will want you to use `NumberLong()` instead of `Long()`

In strict JSON, those values would look something like"

```
{ 
    "_id" : { "$oid" : "5da08d49949b4c000100b90b" }, 
    "ModifiedOn" : { "$date" : "2019-10-11T07:10:17.461-0700" }, 
    "UniqueNumber" : { "$numberLong" : "465561" } 
}
```